# Are there states in the US where Trump supporters are in overwhelming majority?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, presidential-election, joe-biden

Elections are over, Biden has been elected, as we know. But there are about 75 millions of americans, who vote for Trump in 2020. It is interesting for me, how they are allocated - county voting map do not give the full picture, because it is two-colored (I've tried, but couldn't find gradient/density map).

**Are there states in the United States, where people, who vote for Trump in 2020 are in overwhelming (more than 75%) majority?**

Comment: Are you asking just about people who voted for Trump, who may have been Republicans who would rather vote for a Republican president they disliked than a Democrat, or people who actively think that Trump is the best President from all the possible candidates from both parties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*As mentioned in @JoeW's answer, there are no states that Trump won over 75% of the vote share. **However, there are some counties where Trump did win over 75% of the vote share** (FWIW since county-level results [can](https://www.fastcompany.com/90572489/u-s-election-maps-are-wildly-misleading-so-this-designer-fixed-them) [be](https://us.cnn.com/2020/12/17/politics/donald-trump-joe-biden-2020-election/index.html) [misleading](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2020-11-03/a-complete-guide-to-misleading-election-maps) due to the varying sizes of counties). Nevertheless, they can still be an interesting reference.*

---

[The New York Times has a map](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2020/11/03/us/elections/results-president.html) that shows the "Size of lead" of Trump / Biden on a county-level.

[image]

As noted in the footnote:

> Circle size is proportional to the amount each county’s leading candidate is ahead

On GitHub, someone [made the effort](https://github.com/tonmcg/US_County_Level_Election_Results_08-20) to compile the county-level results for the presidential election.

> 2020 election results at the county-level are scraped from results published by from [Fox News](https://www.foxnews.com/elections/2020/general-results), [Politico](https://www.politico.com/2020-election/results/president), and the [New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2020/11/03/us/elections/results-president.html).

**These county-level election results are accessible at https://github.com/tonmcg/US_County_Level_Election_Results_08-20/blob/master/2020_US_County_Level_Presidential_Results.csv.**

---

I downloaded the CSV file and ran the numbers.

- 31.2% of the counties in the US voted for Trump with >75% of the vote share.

  - However, the average total votes of these counties is 9029, compared to the national average of 50,264.

These are the ten largest counties that voted for Trump with >75% of the vote share:

[image]

These are the ten counties with the highest vote share for Trump (don't read too much into this; note their total votes):

[image]

Answer (score 8):

There are no states that voted that way in 2020. The closest would be Wyoming with 69.94% of the vote for trump.

There are areas in states that did get over 75% of the vote for Trump such as Nebraska's third district with 75.36% of the vote but the entire state didn't follow that as Biden did win a district in Nebraska.

Check out wiki for the breakdown by state

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_United_States_presidential_election#Results_by_state

Comment: Still, 276765 votes in total in Wyoming but Wyoming has a population of around 578,795 so how many who is of age to being allow to vote but didn't ? 150,000 ?  So if 425,000 is of age to vote ?  What is the size of US citizens which is of the age to vote now ? 155 millions (or so voted.)

Comment: @StefanSkoglund That is the only metric we have to go by. Also don't forget to count the group of people who are old enough to vote but not eligible for various reasons

Comment: @StefanSkoglund Generally speaking, in a stable population, 25% are under age 18. So 75% of the citizens are voting age. Although at that point it becomes an arithmetic problem, keep in mind that our census population includes people who are not citizens and a relatively small but not .negligible number who have had their voting rights taken away judicially.

Comment: We also have to ask how many of those Wyoming voters were Trump supporters, and how many just thought that he was less bad than Biden would be.

Comment: @jamesqf I don't think it is possible to get that data. And you are missing the voters who vote party line regardless of the candidate so some would have voted for Trump just because he is a Republican.

Comment: @Joe W: Yes, that's why I think any question about the percentage of actual Trump supporters is fundamentally unanswerable.

Comment: @jamesqf Maybe but we can still answer the question about how much of the vote he got.

Comment: @JoeW  I think the reasoning for voting is irrelevant to "support". The vote for a candidate by definition is support.  Half the reason we use the word "support" is because it's impolite to ask who someone voted for.  It's a euphemism.

Comment: @Damila also do not forget that some qualified voters reside elsewhere so they will not have been counted in the census.